# Magento 2.3 my account login it says i am not subscribed

Tags: magento2

When I created my user account, I selected to subscribe to newsletter.
But in my account login it says I am not subscribed.

I checked in the admin backend. It says I am not subscribed also. But I did select the option

Please help me.

Thank you in advance!!!